# Como desabilitar uma option ao criá-la com jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
vetorAux = ["CARROS","Ferrari","Porshe"];
vetorAux.forEach(function(item){
     $('select').append('<option>' + item + '</option>');
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<select>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

Eu gostaria que a opção "CARROS" fosse clicável, pelo menos na primeira vez que o ´select´ carrega,

Depois desse primeiro click gostaria de desabilitar a opção "CARROS". 
Como pode ser resolvido?

Comment: Vc quer que ela fique disabled?

Answer (score 2):

**Realizar algum evento no primeiro option não funciona!**

Veja um exemplo - clicando em `Pagina 1` nada acontece! Só se primeiro clicar em outro option e depois clicar nele.

```js
    function irPara( ) {
    var list = document.forms[0].urlList.value;
    console.log (list);
    }
```

```html
    <form>
    <select name="urlList" size="1" onChange="irPara( )" style=" font-family: ; color:#F5F5F5; background-color:navy; font-size:13px">
    <option value="https://pt.stackoverflow.com/">Pagina 1</option>
    <option value="https://google.com/">Pagina 2</option>
    <option value="https://uol.com/">Pagina 3</option>
    </select>
    </form>
```

***Portanto a solução é colocar um option na primeira posição para ingles ver, capisce?***

```js
vetorAux = ["CARROS","Ferrari","Porshe"];
vetorAux.forEach(function(item){
     $('select').append('<option value="' + item + '">' + item + '</option>');
});



$('#mySelect').change(function() {
  $("#mySelect option[value='CARROS']").prop("disabled",true);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<select id="mySelect">
 <option>Selecione</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @dvd hora de zzzzz, té mais

Answer (score 1):

Basta fazer uma verificação (com `if..else` ou *ternário*) e depois concatenar o valor `disabled` no *option*. Segue exemplo comentado:

```js
vetorAux = ["CARROS","Ferrari","Porshe"];
vetorAux.forEach(function(item){

  /**
   * Verifica se o item é o mesmo que CARROS,
   * caso seja, adiciona "disabled" na variável (informando que o item será desabilitado)
   * caso contrário, adiciona um valor vazio.
   */
  let disabled = (item == "CARROS") ? "disabled" : "";

  /* Concatena os valores */
  $('select').append(`<option ${disabled}>${item}</option>`);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<select>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

Caso seja mais de um valor…

```js
vetorAux = ["CARROS","Ferrari","Porshe"];

/* Indica os valores que deverão ser desabilitados */
vetorAuxDisabled = ["CARROS","Ferrari"];

vetorAux.forEach(function(item){

  /**
   * Verifica se o item está entre os valores que deverão ser desabiltiados,
   * caso esteja, adiciona "disabled" na variável (informando que o item será desabilitado)
   * caso contrário, adiciona um valor vazio.
   */
  let disabled = (vetorAuxDisabled.indexOf(item) >= 0) ? "disabled" : "";

  /* Concatena os valores */
  $('select').append(`<option ${disabled}>${item}</option>`);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<select>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

Caso deseje desabilitar somente após o evento `change`.

```js
const select = document.querySelector("select")

const vetorAux = ["CARROS","Ferrari","Porshe"]

/* Indica os valores que deverão ser desabilitados */
const vetorAuxDisabled = ["CARROS","Ferrari"];

vetorAux.forEach(function(item){
  $('select').append(`<option>${item}</option>`)
});

select.addEventListener("change", el => {

  select.querySelectorAll("option").forEach( item => {
    /**
     * Verifica se o item está entre os valores que deverão ser desabiltiados,
     * caso esteja, desabilita
     */
    if (vetorAuxDisabled.indexOf(item.textContent) >= 0) {
      item.setAttribute("disabled", true)
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<select>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: mas nesse caso o ´disable´ some da lista, eu gostaria que ele ainda fosse clicável, pelo menos na primeira vez que o ´select´ carrega, aí depois que houvesse um "change" ele podoeria desabilitar de vez.
Sem contar que ficaria massante ter que atualizar o vetorAuxDisabled, não tem uma forma mais dinamica?

Comment: @Dr.G Atualizei o exemplo. É possível melhorar o `vetorAuxDisabled`. Porém vai depender da forma que você recebe os dados; Regras de negócios etc.

Comment: Editei a pergunta baseado no comentario do AP acima. Acho que ficou claro o que ele quer.